# My App unintentionally DoSed api, and my IP got blocked across all the sites, now what should I do?

Tags: support

I put a program in cron to run every 5 minutes, and that program loop 5 times and read each api site 12 seconds interval.

But last night (12 hours ago), I noticed that my program broke and there was multiple instances of program running and trying to fetch data in almost every second.

Problem was I didn't set cron to run only one instance of my program, and it taking time more than 5 minutes and duplicating with next cron instances. It was about ***2 Hours*** long!

So, Can I request to unblock my IP here or Should I just wait for automatic release or Just give up?

<sub>**Note**: I only have one hosting, I can't change IP address on my side.</sub>

**Edit**: Looks like it is not temporary, I still can't fetch any data from (api.)?stackoverflow.com, sstatic.net yet until now.

Comment: I believe the correct sacrifice to appease the gods is 3 lambs and a cricket.

Comment: I believe that this is why we test on our local machine before uploading.

Comment: @farseeker even though the day is young (for me at least), I think that's the best comment I'll see all day!

Comment: @S.Mark have you resolved?

Comment: @system, not yet. :( looks like it is semi permanent.

Comment: @S.Mark :-|....

Answer (score 4):

If it were me, I'd email `team@stackoverflow.com`.  They would be the best people to talk to to get this issue resolved.

Comment: yeah, dude. what he said. i would have been spamming them 5 minutes into a lock out.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I ran into a similar problem while developing my first app utilizing Stack Exchange API v2.2 this week. A bit of defensive programming can reduce the impact of unintentional foot-shots. Your app (or multiple copies / threads of your app) won't be getting much done, but you are less likely to get barred.

To avoid having your app permanently blocked, you should be looking for `backoff` in the [Common Wrapper Object](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper) of every response. When told to back off, do so. The following Javascript excerpt does just that:

```
function queryStackExchange( queryString ) {      
  // If we have been asked to back off by Stack Exchange API, exit
  var backoffUntil = properties.getProperty("backoff");
  if (backoffUntil) {
    if (now() < backoffUntil) {
      return {"backoff":backoffUntil};
    }
    else {
      // backoff completed; delete snooze setting
      properties.deleteProperty("backoff");
    }
  }

  // OK to proceed - build our query
  ...
  var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  var obj = JSON.parse(json);

  // Check for backoff request, and set our snooze period
  if ("backoff" in obj) {
    backoffUntil = now() + 1000*parseInt(obj["backoff"]);
    properties.setProperty("backoff", backoffUntil);
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

E-mail us (use the contact link) with the IP and your case details.

Answer (score 0):

Wait unit 00:00 GMT and  your rate-limit will be reset.

unless you tripped some wire I am not aware of and got on a black list.

Comment: I think its more than rate-limit issue though, but let's see